# Can I have both married and maiden names on my French ID card?

Tags: france, french-citizens

During my interview at my regional prefecture for application for French nationality (dual in fact because I hold a British passport in my married name) the interviewer noticed that I had omitted to include my married name on the first page of my application form. Only my maiden name was entered. She queried this and said that should I be granted French nationality it was likely that my French ID card would be in my maiden name.

Although I have been divorced for over 30 years I still use my married name. Is it possible to ask for both names to appear on my new card and who should I write to about this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it would possible, since you're been, and France considers that you don't have a link to that name any longer. However, generally speaking if you want to a family name to your ID papers (ID card, passport), there's a line or two in the form for a **request** to add an extra name. Usually it's called a *nom d'usage*, and would appear after your last name. Say your maiden name is Davies, and your ex-husband is Smith, were the request to be accepted, your family name would read:

> Davies, usage Davies-Smith

However, I have never seen a naturalisation form, so I've no clue whether this is an option or not. What you can try to do is when applying for a French passport, and fill out the optional lines for the extra name request. But whether this will be accepted is another story.

Comment: On the naturalisation form, as far as I am aware, they only accept Francisations of names. So I think she could change her name to Françoise, but I don't think she could change her Anglicised name. There are rules to the Francisation of names, but I don't know what they are.